# SqlParameters to DBContext executesqlcommand

Tags: c#, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5

we are using vs 2012.

I wrote the below method to execute executesqlcommand on dbcontext.

```
  //Check lock conditions for site part vrsm
  public bool CanLock(int spvId)
  {
        SqlParameter output = new SqlParameter("editMode", SqlDbType.Bit);
        output.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter("spvId", SqlDbType.Int);
        parameter.Value = spvId;
        ExecuteProcedure("exec [dbo].[prc_SitePartVrsn_CanLock] {0}, @editMode = {1} output", parameter, output);

        return Convert.ToBoolean(output.Value);
   }
```

This is very old way of passing parameters.
Do we have any better way of doing it in c# 4.5 vs 2012.

please help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from your syntax, which will throw an error for you, that's pretty much the only way to do it. I have corrected the syntax below:

```
SqlParameter output = new SqlParameter("editMode", SqlDbType.Bit);
output.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter("spvId", SqlDbType.Int);
parameter.Value = spvId;

ExecuteProcedure("exec [dbo].[prc_SitePartVrsn_CanLock] @spvId, @editMode OUTPUT", parameter, output);

bool retVal = (bool)output.Value; // same result as using Convert.ToBoolean
```

**edit** Unless you want to use something like

```
var p = new SqlParameter {
    ParameterName = "paramName",
    DbType = DbType.Bit,
    Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
};
```